# How to use another way to implements a rollback flow using Workflow Core Library?

Tags: asp.net-core, workflow, workflow-engine

I use json define workflow like the following picture:

[image]

But when the steps nodes become more and more,the decision branch may not be a good solution(because more and more repetitive json code).

So I want another way to realize the process with rollback function.
Who can tell me another way to use the WorkflowCore library to achieve my purpose? I'll be deeply grateful!